# How to write cardinality property of an statistical dataset

Tags: statistics, notation, machine-learning

Consider statistical dataset $D$ where every variable $X$ has assigned single label $y \in \{0, 1\}$. How to, using math notation, write that dataset $D$ contains much less labels $y=1$ than labels $y=0$?

Comment: You can define $D_0 = \{ X \mid X=0 \}$ and $D_1 = \{ X \mid X=1 \}$. Then, using $|A|$ for the cardinality of $A$, we have that $|D_1| >> |D_0|$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.